# Алгоритм фильтрации товаров

Tags: javascript, алгоритм, node.js

```js
let aside = document.body.querySelector('aside'),
  set = new Set(),
  arr = [];

aside.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let target = event.target;
  let click = false;

  while (target != aside) {
    if (target.tagName == 'LABEL') {
      let text = target.querySelector('span.label').textContent,
        check = target.querySelector('input');

      if (check.checked && check.getAttribute('type') == 'checkbox') {
        set.add(text);
      } else {
        set.delete(text);
      }

      if (check.checked && check.getAttribute('type') == 'radio') {
        set.add(text);
      } else {
        let newText;

        if (target.nextSibling && check.getAttribute('type') == 'radio') {
          newText = target.nextSibling.querySelector('span.label').textContent;
        }

        if (target.previousSibling && check.getAttribute('type') == 'radio') {
          newText = target.previousSibling.querySelector('span.label').textContent;
        }

        set.delete(newText);
        click = true;
      }

    }

    target = target.parentNode;
  }

  if (click == false) {
    return;
  }

  arr.length = 0;

  arr = [...set];

  let json = JSON.stringify(arr);

  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('POST', 'server.js', true);
  xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
  xhr.send(json);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
    if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;

    let object = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    let article = document.querySelector('article');

    while (article.lastChild) {
      article.removeChild(article.lastChild);
    };

    for (let value in object) {
      let template = document.querySelector('#template').content;
      let item = template.querySelector('.item');

      let newItem = item.cloneNode(true);
      newItem.querySelector('img').src = `${object[value].img}`;
      newItem.querySelector('.description').textContent = object[value].description;
      newItem.querySelector('.price-rub').textContent = object[value].rub;
      newItem.querySelector('.price-penny').textContent = object[value].penny;
      newItem.querySelector('.country').textContent = object[value].country;
      article.appendChild(newItem);
    }

  }

});
```

```html
<aside>
  <section>
    <h3>Страна производства</h3><label> <input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">Беларусь</span></label><label> <input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">Россия</span></label><label> <input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">Украина</span></label><label> <input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">Нидерланды</span></label><label> <input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">Германия</span></label></section>
  <section>
    <h3>Цена</h3>
    <div class="price-range"><input type="number" placeholder="от: " min="0" /><input type="number" placeholder="до: " min="1" /></div>
  </section>
  <section>
    <h3>Количество в упаковке</h3><label><input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">1</span></label><label><input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">4 </span></label><label><input type="checkbox"/><span class="checkbox"></span><span class="label">8</span></label></section>
  <section>
    <h3>Наличие втулки</h3>
    <div class="radio"><label><input type="radio" name="sss"/><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="label">Да</span></label><label><input type="radio" name="sss"/><span class="radiobutton"></span><span class="label">Нет</span></label></div>
  </section>
</aside>
```

Решил написать интернет-магазин для практики. При каждом нажатии по **чекбоксам** сохраняю их значение(**label**) в массив и через **AJAX** посылаю их на сервер, где сравниваю их с полями объекта.

Пример объекта:

```
{
    img: "picture/52.jpg",
    description: "Туалетная бумага „Kleenex“ нежная ромашка, трехслойная, 8 рулонов.",
    rub: "9р.",
    penny: "99к.",
    country: "Россия",
    sleeve: "Да",
    amount: 8
},
{
    img: "picture/53.jpg",
    description: "Туалетная бумага „Kleenex“ сочная клубника, трехслойная, 8 рулонов.",
    rub: "9р.",
    penny: "99к.",
    country: "Россия",
    sleeve: "Да",
    amount: 8
}
```

Код фильтрации на сайте:

```
object.length = 0;
set.clear();

for (let i of set) {
    set.delete(set[i]);
}

arr.forEach(obj => {
    for (let value in obj) {
        for (let i = 0; i < req.body.length; i++) {

            if (obj[value] == req.body[i]) {
                count++;
                set.add(obj);
            }

        }
    }
})

object = [...set];
json = JSON.stringify(object)
res.end(json);
```

Знаю, что это неправильный код, т.к. он добавляет товар даже в том случае, если только один из критериев удовлетворяет. **Как реализовать поиск товаров, удовлетворяющий сразу нескольким пунктам?** Возможно надо посылать не массив, а массив массивов. В любом случае я не могу додуматься :)

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, через "req.body" я получаю тот массив значений, который отправляю на сервер. Res.end - посылаю сформированный массив объектов назад. Или вы имеете ввиду добавить метку Nodы?)

Comment: @Рустам Гимранов, тут проблема как раз вообще не в них. В алгоритме)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> target.nextSibling.querySelector('span.label').textContent

Могу ошибаться: возможно, что на серверах с Node это делается именно так, но, наверное, вместо таких конструкций все же стоит воспользоваться тегом `form`, задать всем полям ввода (*input*, *select*, *checkbox*) атрибуты `name`, `value` и собирать данные при помощи [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects). Конечно, если вы не практикуетесь в выборках узлов по DOM.

```js
document.getElementById('filter_form')
  .addEventListener('input', function(event) {
    const formData = new FormData(this);

    log(formData);

    /**
     * Пример отправки FormData.
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', API_URL, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xhr.status === 200) {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

        // Рендеринг списка товаров.
        console.log(response);
      }
    }

    xhr.send(formData);*/
  });

const log = function logToConsoleforDemo(data) {
  console.clear();
  console.log('Эти данные будут отправлены:');

  for (let pair of data.entries()) {
    console.log(...pair);
  }
};
```

```css
#app {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.sidebar {
  flex: 0 0 288px;
  padding: 18px;
  padding-bottom: 188px;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <aside class="sidebar">
    <form id="filter_form" action="" method="post">
      <section>
        <h3>Страна производства</h3>
        <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="belarus" />
              <span class="checkbox"></span>
              <span class="label">Беларусь</span>
            </label>
        <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="russia" />
              <span class="checkbox"></span>
              <span class="label">Россия</span>
            </label>
        <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="ukraine" />
              <span class="checkbox"></span>
              <span class="label">Украина</span>
            </label>
        <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="netherlands" />
              <span class="checkbox"></span>
              <span class="label">Нидерланды</span>
            </label>
        <label>
              <input type="checkbox" name="country[]" value="germany" />
              <span class="checkbox"></span>
              <span class="label">Германия</span>
            </label>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h3>Цена</h3>
        <div class="price-range">
          <input type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="от: " min="100" value="100" />
          <input type="number" name="price[]" placeholder="до: " min="1000" value="1000" />
        </div>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h3>Количество в упаковке</h3>
        <select name="quantity-per-pack">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
      </section>
      <section>
        <h3>Наличие втулки</h3>
        <div class="radio">
          <label>
                <input type="radio" name="thimble" value="1" />
                <span class="radiobutton"></span>
                <span class="label">Да</span>
              </label>
          <label>
                <input type="radio" name="thimble" value="0" />
                <span class="radiobutton"></span>
                <span class="label">Нет</span>
              </label>
        </div>
      </section>
    </form>
  </aside>
  <main class="main"></main>
</div>
```

---

> Как реализовать поиск товаров, удовлетворяющий сразу нескольким пунктам?

Небольшой пример, просто он нагляднее без использования `for`:

```js
// Массив товаров.
const products = [{
  "name": "Первый",
  "price": "100",
  "country": "russia",
  "thimble": "true",
}, {
  "name": "Второй",
  "price": "200",
  "country": "belarus",
  "thimble": "true",
}, {
  "name": "Третий",
  "price": "1000",
  "country": "russia",
  "thimble": "false",
}, {
  "name": "Четвертый",
  "price": "800",
  "country": "netherlands",
  "thimble": "false",
}];

// Предположим, что это фильтр с фронта.
const query = {
  "country": [
    "netherlands",
    "belarus"
  ],
  "thimble": "false"
};

// Ключи из фильтра, по ним будет фильтрация.
const queryKeys = Object.keys(query);

// Здесь желательно не забывать о типах данных.
// ... code.

// Фильтрация массива объектов по нескольким ключам.
const filtered = products.filter((product) => {
  // При помощи метода `every` проверяем,
  // чтобы значения каждого ключа совпадали
  // со значениями ключей в товаре.
  return queryKeys.every((key) => {
    // Если несколько значений у ключа.
    // В нашем случае это массив `country` с фронта.
    if (Array.isArray(query[key])) {
      return query[key].includes(product[key]);
    }

    return product[key] == query[key];
  });
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Comment: Это гениально!! Спасибо большое. А о formData я и не слышал ничего, надо освежить знания. Ещё раз спасибо)

Comment: я проверил :) немного переписать надо, но главное, что работает